# android fragment livedata remove observer not working

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am using jetpack navigation for navigating. I observer the form submit with viewmodel livedata.

I am observing livedata in onActivityCreated of the fragment (SignUpFragment) like.

```
viewModel.signup.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<Resource<BaseResponse<User>>> {
        checkSignUpResponse(it)
})
```

after i am navigated to the next fragment (OtpFragment) when i am using navigationUp() sign up observer called method in observer (checkSignUpResponse) and sending me to otp fragment again.

i tried

```
viewModel.signup.removeObservers(viewLifecycleOwner)
```

and also

```
viewModel.signup.removeObserver(signUpObserver)
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: can you show the `signUpObserver` assignment?

Comment: signUpObserver is just a object with checkSignUpResponse() methid call. i used data binding also thats why all viewmodel live value values are automatically assigend. but problem is how to prevent observer to call when navigated back.

Comment: have you found out the possible solution? If yes, can you please share it I am also running into the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just used isNavigatedToOtp boolean switched while navigating n check weather is isNavigatedToOtp false n then called checkSignUpResponse.

Comment: but i am not sure is correct way of doing. but it works!